# add code syntax color winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

In my winform application I allow the user to write/read some c# code (simple text in a RichTextBox, I would like to add the functionality to highlight the syntax like VS or notepad++ does, nothing advanced like intellisense and so on, just the text colour change would do.

I've been looking around but I couldn't find anything, do you know if there's a ready to use library or something that I can use?

Comment: Read the [help] about what's on topic in this site.

Comment: oh, sorry didn't know @Steve, Do you know where should I ask this question?

Comment: Well, you could start with researching the controls you've got available, like the rich text controls, and consider how to parse the source for highlighting as RTF; or even look at how open source editors have done it as a first option. StackOverflow is a great place for asking about solving specific issues you come up against with your implementation

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow, shall I delete the question then or can I leave it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox/) component which seems to be exactly what I need, answering in here in case someone else needs it.